# How to join tidy datasets and merge the columns

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I have two tidy tibbles with one matching key column (ID) and several columns with the same name, but different row values. 
I would like to join the two tibbles by ID and to add the additional measurements, timestamps and values of df2 to the respective columns in df1.

So far, I've tried to full_join, merge, left_join etc.:

```
joined_df <- full_join(df1, df2, by="ID")
```

But this returns a tibble with additional time, value and measurements columns (time.x, value.x etc.).

I, however, would like to add those additional df2-values to the already existing columns of df1 by ID, so that the resulting df has added rows, but no added columns.

Here's an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
                  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
                  measurement = c(x,s,d,g,u,b,z,e)
                  xy = c(g,h,j,k,t,d,g,t)
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  time = c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18), 
                  value = c(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
                  measurement = c(r,t,z,u,i,o,k,f)
                  ab = c(j,k,o,l,p,f,b,c)
```

What I need is a join function that expands the ID column by the number of added rows from df2, and includes the additional measurements, values and timestamps from df2 into the existing columns of df1. 
The expected output would be:

```
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18), 
                  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
                  measurement = c(x,s,d,g,u,b,z,e,r,t,z,u,i,o,k,f)
                  xy = c(g,h,j,k,t,d,g,t,g,h,j,k,t,d,g,t)
                  ab = c(j,k,o,l,p,f,b,c,j,k,o,l,p,f,b,c))
```

Somehow I wasn't able to find sth. like that yet. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)`

Comment: Yes that's true, but the problem is that I also have other columns in both dfs (forgot to add them in the example, sorry), that I would like to add by ID. So basically the columns (here) "xy" and "ab" should be added by ID, the columns "measurement" and "value" should be expanded.

Comment: Provide expected output for these 2 dataframes when merged.

Comment: I did (df3). I tried to bind rows and then full_join only the additional columns of each dataframe by fieldId, but that made my R crash O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it now by using a combination of bind_rows and left_join:

```
df3 <- bind_rows(df1[,c(2,3,5,6)], df2[,c(1,3,4,5)])

df1_lookup <- 
  df1 %>% select(ID,xy,cv) %>% distinct()

df2_lookup <- 
  df2 %>% select(ID,ab) %>% distinct()

df3 %>% left_join(df1_lookup, by="ID") %>% left_join(df2_lookup, by="ID")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_missing_columns <- function(from, to) {
  to[setdiff(names(from), names(to))] <- from[setdiff(names(from), names(to))]
  to
}
df2 <- add_missing_columns(from = df1, to = df2)
df1 <- add_missing_columns(from = df2, to = df1)
res <- rbind(df1, df2)
all.equal(df3, res)
# TRUE
```

---

With data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
                  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                  measurement = c(
                     "x", "s", "d", "g", "u", "b", "z", "e"),
                  xy = c(
                     "g", "h", "j", "k", "t", "d", "g", "t"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  time = c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18), 
                  value = c(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
                  measurement = c(
                     "r", "t", "z", "u", "i", "o", "k", "f"),
                  ab = c(
                     "j", "k", "o", "l", "p", "f", "b", "c"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                  time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18), 
                  value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
                  measurement = c(
                     "x", "s", "d", "g", "u", "b", "z", "e", "r", "t", "z", "u", "i", "o", "k", "f"),
                  xy = c(
                     "g", "h", "j", "k", "t", "d", "g", "t", "g", "h", "j", "k", "t", "d", "g", "t"),
                  ab = c(
                     "j", "k", "o", "l", "p", "f", "b", "c", "j", "k", "o", "l", "p", "f", "b", "c"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't that just bind the missing columns of each df to the other without considering the fieldId as a unique key for the join?

Comment: What is expected to be found in the resulting "join" (that would make it a join, not a union)?